# How do I use jQuery to get combined widths of DIVs in a container and pass that value on to another element?

Tags: jquery, width, dimensions

I'm hoping to use jQuery to get the total widths of all the DIVs in a container and set that width to the body.

I presume I need something to the effect of

```
$('#container > div').width().[mulitply by quantity of DIVs in container].[set this result to body width]
```

Unfortunately just typing strings of what I want isn't good enough! Can someone point me in the right direction?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: please make sure you cannot achieve this with css only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could look like:

```
var overall_width = 0;

$('#container > div').each(function(index, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    overall_width += $elem.outerWidth() + parseInt($elem.css('margin-left'), 10) + parseInt($elem.css('margin-right'), 10);
});

$(document.body).width(overall_width);
```

This would add all the children `div node`'s width along with the *margin* (if there is any) and finally set the *width* from `document.body`.

Comment: FYI `.outerWidth()` takes a single boolean argument, which if set `true` will also include the margin. So in this case you can just do `$elem.outerWidth(true)`. - http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/